# Avro 1.8.2 Java code generation for BigDecimal (Logical Type)

Tags: java, maven, avro

How do I generate `BigDecimal` in my `Apple` class? Right now all I have is a `ByteBuffer`....

Using Avro Schema (avsc):

```
{"namespace": "com.example",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Apple",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "price",  "type": {
                                          "type": "bytes",
                                          "logicalType": "decimal",
                                          "precision": 9,
                                          "scale": 2
                                        }}
  ]
}
```

Using IDL:

```
@namespace("com.example")
protocol AppleProtocol {
    record Apple {
        @java-class("java.math.BigDecimal") decimal(9,2) price;
    }
}
```

Using the maven generating method `mvn clean compile`, and the following maven snippet:

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/avro</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Both these things return this ugly method that is obviously barely usable...

```
public void setPrice(java.nio.ByteBuffer value) {
    this.price = value;
  }
```

How can I get this method to ask for a `BigDecimal`?
This is using Avro `1.8.2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the generated classes to represent decimal logical types with BigDecimal instead of ByteBuffer, set 
the Avro Maven plugin configuration parameter `enableDecimalLogicalType` to true.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
                <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <enableDecimalLogicalType>true</enableDecimalLogicalType>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Any reason why this isn't a default behaviour ?